# ¿Porque los datos se muestran al contrario?

Tags: php

Las consultas son realizadas mediante consultas preparadas de mysqli, la variable `$previa` puede traer dos tipos de resultados `yes` o `not`

La consulta es realizada por medio de datos relacionados un ejemplo:

```
id  articulo  previa  id_articulo
 1    algo     yes        2
 2    algo1    yes        2
```

Como se observa se traen resultados del mismo id del articulo.

Y los resultados son lo siguiente:

algo  -> not
algo1 -> not

Pero debería ser de esta manera ya que en la base de datos esta datos como `yes`

algo  -> yes
algo1 -> yes

> **Nota:** Pero si llego cambiar el valor `yes` por `not` ahí si muestra el resultado que debería mostrar, pero todo se esta haciendo al revés.

Estoy utilizando el siguiente código:

```
if($previa!="yes"){
  echo $articulo;
  echo 'yes';
} else {
  echo $articulo;
  echo 'not';
}
```

Comment: no sera porque estas diciendo en tu if que si es diferente a yes imprima not de lo contrario que imprima yes?

Comment: si te sirvio la respuesta por favor da un puntito +1 jeje

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que tener en cuenta que el operador `!=` significa **distinto de**.

En tu caso, estás diciendo que si es distinto de `yes`, es decir, `no`, muestre `not` por pantalla y viceversa.

Tendrías que cambiar el operador de tu `if` para realizar una comparación. Para indicar si una variable es igual a algo se utiliza el doble `==` (o triple `===` si quieres una comparación exacta).

Quedaría así tu comparación:

```
if($previa=="yes"){
  echo $articulo;
  echo 'yes';
} else {
  echo $articulo;
  echo 'not';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba esta evaluación con operadores ternarios:

```
$articulo='articulo-1';
$previa='yes';
$str=($previa=='yes') ? $articulo.' '.$previa : $articulo.' '.$previa;
echo $str.PHP_EOL;


$articulo='articulo-2';
$previa='no';
$str=($previa=='yes') ? $articulo.' '.$previa : $articulo.' '.$previa;
echo $str.PHP_EOL;
```

**Output:**

```
articulo-1 yes
articulo-2 no
```

### Conclusión

Con esta sola línea bastaría:

```
$str=($previa=='yes') ? $articulo.' '.$previa : $articulo.' '.$previa;
```

O bien, si quieres un `not` cuando no sea sí, lo cambias por esto:

```
$str=($previa=='yes') ? $articulo.' '.$previa : $articulo.' not';
```

Answer (score 1):

si yes es diferente de yes {echo $echo 'yes';}si no {echo $articulo;
      echo 'not';}

```
if($previa!="yes"){
  echo $articulo;
  echo 'yes';
} else {
  echo $articulo;
  echo 'not';
}
```

esta mal es si yes es igual que yes echo $articulo; echo 'yes'; else {echo $articulo;
          echo 'not';}

```
if($previa==="yes"){
      echo $articulo;
      echo 'yes';
    } else {
      echo $articulo;
      echo 'not';
    }
```